# Bad practise? Take row by username, then do validations if passwords match and then add to session?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

```
$user = \App\User::where("name", $req->us)->firstOrFail();
```

then:

```
if(Hash::check($plain_text_password, $user->password)){
   //add user to session
}
else{
  //bad credentials
}
```

I'm aware of other methods available in Laravel, I'm asking about this specific situation.

Comment: and use middleware to filter the requests.

Comment: That's usually the other way around: Raw input vs. hashed in database using the password verification function.

Comment: Yeah, my bad...

Comment: I fixed it, so the question's still the same. Is it bad to do so? Get password by username and then check it using the functions and if everything goes well, then add the session?

Comment: if you are using laravel, why not take advantage of `Auth Middleware` and use Auth::attempt() instead?

Comment: I said that I don't want to create my custom auth or use this.
I need more precise error messages
If username and password is good => check if it is activated, if not => 'not activated'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

**Approach 1.** You can add both username password in the where condition.

If the username and password not matching, The error message will be like "Invalid Username and password"

**Approach 2.** (Your approach). Get the user record from the user table using `where("name", $req->us)` and validate the password `if(Hash::check($user->password, $user->password))`. The advantage in this approach is you can show the error message like below.

- If the username is not in the table, you can display error like "Invalid Username".
- If the password is not matching, you can display error like "Invalid Password".

You can use any approach and from a security perspective you can go with the approach 1.

Comment: That's great to hear. Although I made a mistake in the the code. If you can, please fix your post, it should've been like this
Hash::check($plain_text_password, $user->password)

Thank you for answering. I was aware of the 1st one, although I wanted more flexibility, I know it is possible to edit/extend already pre-built Auth controller for my liking, but I wanted a more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using following code since it is more cleaner approach to check if username exists in database and then login ?

```
// do validation 
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username'    =>    'required|exists:users',
    'password'    =>    'required' 
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
     return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator); 
}

// try login using given credentials 
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->input('username'), 'password' =>   $request->input('password')])) {
       // Authentication passed...
       return redirect()->intended('dashboard'); 
}
```

Comment: else { // authentication not passed  }
I need two different messages:
'user is not activated, check email'
'bad password/username'

I don't want to use Auth::attempt, because as far as I know I cant tell whether an account is activated, I know I can add more parameters to attempt to check other fields, but if it fails it goes to 'else'.